# Telegram bot sendVideo aspectRatio

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I use sendVideo method with file url, so telegram automatically create preview for my video, determines duration and aspect ratio of preview.

But it incorrectly determines aspect ratio of preview, so it looks weird. (I suspect that it has some problem with this task, because all wrong sizes are square ( default aspect ratio))

Is there any approach to fix this issue ? I have tried to manually set width\height in api call, but telegram does not respect this parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened my video with HandBrake program and I've found, that it has different storage size and preview size (because of me, truncating this video).

Telegram respects storage size, so I processed my video with HandBrake to achieve equal sizes, after that preview of my video became correct.